# How is infinite scrolling made?

Tags: php, jquery, infinite-scroll

How struggling to make a PHP call to get items to load on scroll. I have a while loop of items and need a php code for infinity.php to load more items to the ID "stream" but can't figure out a solution. Would be greatful for some expertise help!

PHP on Main-page:

```
<?php
$getStream = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$DBprefix."xxx WHERE xxx='xxx' AND status='1' ORDER by id");

$counter = 0;
$max = 2;

while($stream = mysql_fetch_array($getStream) and ($counter < $max)) {
$counter++;

  }
?>
```

I have this Jquery:

```
    function lastAddedLiveFunc()
{
    $('div#loader').fadeIn();

    $.get("infinity.php", function(data){
        if (data != "") {
            //console.log('add data..');
            $("#stream").append(data);
        }
        $('div#loader').empty();
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id='stream'></div>
```

Comment: The bane of your existence will be within `mysql_`. that library is deprecated, full of flaws, and leaves you incredibly vulnerable. Please consider the use of `mysqli_` or even better, `pdo` (php data objects)

Comment: Create a php file that can accept a get variable that serves as a counter of where in the database to select. When the jquery list reaches the end, poll the server for where to start at, then append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a few key pieces here. Firstly, when we use infinte scroll and we're fetching data from the database, you need a `LIMIT` clause, the LIMIT clause allows for a `offset, total` relationship. where offset indicates the row to start at, and total is how many rows we want to take.

Initially, you'll have something like this

```
$offset = $_GET['offset'] ? $_GET['offset'] : 0; //start at 0th row if no variable set
$total = $_GET['total'] ? $_GET['total'] : 20; // get 20 rows if no variable set
```

In the above, we're using ternary variable assignment to check if an argument is being passed to us, if not, then we use the default value. We're going to use mysqli and the prepared, bind_param, execute, bind_result and fetch_assoc() methods.

```
if( $getStream = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE xxx=? AND status=? ORDER by id LIMIT ?,?"):

    $ret = ''; // a variable place holder

    // in the above statement, fill in the ?'s
    // the actual ? will be the value we wish to return, in order from first to last.
    $getStream->bind_param('ssddd', $DBprefix.'xxx', 'xxx', 1, $offset, $total);

    //execute our query
    $getStream->execute();

    $getStream->bind_result($field1, $field2, $field3, $field4); // each field needs it's own variable name, that way we can access them later.

    while($row = $getStream->fetch_assoc()):
        $ret .= '<div class="my-infinite-element"><h3>'. $field1 .'</h3><p>'. $field2.'</p>'. $field3 .', '. $field4 .'</div>';
    endwhile;

    echo $ret;

else:
    return FALSE;
endif;
```

Now that's how we'll handle getting our data back using MySQLI; now let's make the ajax statement to get the data back.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url : 'infinity.php',
    data: {
        'offset' : $('.my-infinite-elements').length,
        'total' : 20
    },
    success: function(data){
        if(false !== data){
            $('#stream').append(data);
        }
    } 
});
```

In the above, the only thing we should be worried about is `$('.my-infinite-elements').length`. We used a class of `my-infinite-elements` for each element we returned. This way, we can count the existing length of elements on the page, which will provide our `offset` value (or where we want to start getting the rows from). If we pulled out 20 results from our DB, it's 0 based, so we'll get 0-19. When we do `.length`, we're going to get a `1 based` result, which will return `20`, instead of 19. That's okay, because we DON'T want the very last row returned also, so our logic is fine. The two variables `offset/total` in our ajax function, correspond to our ternary variable assignment.

Comment: Thanks for a really good explaination! But unfortunately I'm still struggling to get it to work.. :(

Comment: I get the "load more" to work, but it just loops everything on and on again. And some dynamic elements inside each element like, facebook like buttons and onclick functions doesn't work

Comment: Using my code you recieve a loop? We shouldn't, because of the dynamic calculation of the length, as for `click functions` within the element, that's an issue of `event delegation`, which requires the events to be bound to a static parent element, and delegated to the dynamic one, such as `$(document).on('click', 'myElement', function(){ alert('Dynamic Delegation!'); });`. Where document is static, never gets removed/readded, and `myElement` is the selector for the dynamic Element.

Comment: Thanks, now the .on click works great for all elements! I think I better take a little break and then go back to fix the loop limits. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Kim please replace `document` with the closest static parent element that exists at page load and is never removed/replaced, which looks like `$('#stream')`